# How to resolve DVC Pull Error on Pycharm?

Tags: python, dvc

When I execute 'DVC Pull', I get the following error

```
> dvc pull ERROR: unexpected error - invalid syntax (tz.py, line 78)    
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/jasma/miniconda3/envs/earth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dvc/main.py",
> line 55, in main
>     ret = cmd.do_run()   File "/home/jasma/miniconda3/envs/earth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dvc/command/base.py",
 "/home/jasma/miniconda3/envs/earth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dateutil/tz.py",
> line 78
>     `self._name`,
>     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[How to resolve it? The link to the Github repository is](https://github.com/jasma-balasangameshwara/ml-heroku-fastapi)

Comment: Error resolved! I ran 'DVC destroy' and re-started the entire process beginning from initializing DVC.

Comment: Sounds like maybe there was some project corruption? If you come across this again please open an issue on Github or contact support at dvc.org/chat .